# Oauth2 Parameter Matchup

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0

I'm new to rest and oauth. I was granted developer access to my law firm's billing software. I received a "developer account" with a username and password, and I registered my "app", at which point the sum total of all information I have is the following:

1. API Key
2. Secret Key
3. Username used to register the app (an email address)
4. Password used to register the app
5. The app name, which I came up with
6. The redirect url, which I provided

The "documentation" says that I need to pass the following URL-encoded line in the body of my request, with all parameters being required:

*client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&grant_type={grant_type}&code={code}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}*

I'm having a little trouble figuring out what's what. I believe *client_id* and *client_secret* are the *api key* and *secret key* provided when I registered the app. Does that sound correct?

I have no idea which grant type to use.

I have no idea what the "code" is or where to get it.

It almost seems like the developers didn't give me all the info I needed, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't seem like enough info! Yes the API key and secret sound like the `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Generally the grant type will be dependent on what type of application you are developing. The most commonly used ones are:

- Web App with user = `Authorisation Code` Grant
- Javascript Browser App = `Implicit` Grant
- Native / Mobile App = `Authorisation Code` Grant with PKCE.
- Web App / API with no user context required = `Client Credentials`
  Grant.

With the information you provide I'm not sure of the best fit for you but here's an example of the usual protocol to get a token using a couple of grant types:

> The Authorisation Code Grant:

So you would make 2 calls to the law firm's Authorisation server:

```
1) GET /authorize?response_type=code&client_id=yourclientid
            &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyourappserver%2Ecom%2Fcallback HTTP/1.1
```

You would get a code sent back to your redirect endpoint which you'd then send on to the /token endpoint of the auth server.

```
2)  POST /token HTTP/1.1
         Host: server.yourlawfirm.com
         Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
         Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    
         grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
         &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyourappserver%2Ecom%2Fcallback
```

Note in this example the basic authentication code contains the client id and secret but often they are sent in the request body e.g.

```
2)  POST /token HTTP/1.1
         Host: server.yourlawfirm.com
         Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    
         grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA
         &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyourappserver%2Ecom%2Fcallback
         &client_id=yourclientid&client_secret=yoursecret
```

The authorisation server would then return you an access token from step 2)

If your application is going to talk to the law firm's billing software without the need for / context of a user then you would use the client credentials grant.

> The Client Credentials Grant.

An example of this protocol is one call to the law firm's Auth server:

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.yourlawfirm.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=client_credentials
```

And this would return an access token.

Again the client id and secret are wrapped up in the basic auth header but it may be that you can supply them in the request body as I showed before.

e.g.

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.yourlawfirm.com 
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=yourclientid&client_secret=yoursecret
```

This information is based on the [OAuth2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

Comment: I see. It looks like the missing piece of information is the authorization address that I pass the client_id to in order to get the authorization code.

Comment: So, I think I need an authorization endpoint, correct? I should be clear that I'm just using a console application, no webserver, and the app registration I created on their site lists the redirect_url as localhost:999. Should they have an authorization endpoint that they neglected to provide me, or is that something I have to do on my own? Sorry, Oauth2 is so confusing to me.

Comment: If you don't have to ask a user to log in then you are either using the `client credentials` grant (described in my answer) or the `Resource Owner Password Credentials` grant (where you supply a username and password as well as your client credentials). These flows do not need to call an authorise endpoint, as no user is asked to authorise.